# Is this type of function continuous?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

[Pic of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CXWm.png)

Is this function continius along the x axis?

Comment: What do you think ?

Comment: What is the relevance of the following questions: [1] If $f,g$ are two continuous functions with the same domain $D$, and $g$ is never zero in $D$, what can you say about the function $(f/g)$? [2] What happens when $Q(x) = 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type is called as a rational function. It being a ratio of 2 polynomials, will be continuous everywhere, except at those points where the denominator goes to $0$, called the zeros of the function. It can have at most $m$ discontinuities, where $m$ is the degree of the polynomial in the denominator.